# segmentation fault only using valgrind

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I'm programming a spellchecker for an class assignment. The first step is to load a list separated by "\n" in a "dict" (that actually is a char** dict_main).

The procedure to load the dict is the next:

```
void dict_load(char *fname){
    FILE *loaded_file = fopen(fname, "r");
    char **aux = NULL;
    int a = 0;
    char word[MAX_WORD_SIZE];

    //Checks whether fname was successfully loaded or not
    if(loaded_file == NULL){
        perror("Could not load dict\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        while(fgets(word, MAX_WORD_SIZE, loaded_file) != NULL){
            main_size++;
            while(aux == NULL){
                //To ensure that aux is not NULL
                aux = realloc(dict_main, main_size);
            }
            dict_main = aux;
            aux = NULL;
            //Allocs space enough to store word
            dict_main[main_size-1] = calloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(dict_main[main_size-1], word);
        }
    }

    //Just for debbuging, prints each string in dict_main
    for(a = 0; a<main_size; a++){
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", dict_main[a]);
    }
    fclose(loaded_file);
}
```

This seems to work when I run it normaly, but when I use valgrind, I get a segfault when it tries to printf the strings.

This is the only procedure that runs in the program, this is main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   char *dict;
   //int i;
   if (argc < 2)
     {
       printf("spellchecker.c: nro de argumentos erroneo. Deben ser <documento> [<diccionario>].\n");
       return (1);
     }
   dict = (argc >=3) ? argv[2] : "dict.txt";
   dict_main = calloc(main_size, sizeof(char*));

   dict_load(dict);

   free(dict_main);

   printf("El documento %s ha sido procesado. Resultados en out.txt\n", argv[1]);
```

Is there something I'm missing and gets me that SegFault when I run it with valgrind?
    }

Comment: `aux = realloc(dict_main, main_size*sizeof(char*));`

Comment: Your `while(aux==NULL)` loop won't work for what you intend.  It'll just loop forever - because if it does return NULL, you just run it again with no changes in the process's heap - you don't free any memory to try again.

Comment: Yes, it was that the realloc was wrong. dict_main is a global char** (it was given to us like this in the base code). I fixed the realloc and now everything runs ok. I'll check the while(aux==NULL).

Comment: I removed the incorrect comments that I had written